# Color changed on button in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

I use AlertDialogs a lot in my project on multiple Activities.

On one om my activities the AlertDialog changed color on the buttons (making them ugly and unreadable).

I use the same theme all throughout my app.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateReservationActivity.this)
        .setMessage(alertMessage)
        .setTitle(alertTitle)
        .setNeutralButton("Ok", null) // ignore button click
        .setCancelable(true)
        .create();
alertDialog.show();
```

How it looks in one of the acitivities

[image]

How it looks in every other activity.

[image]

Comment if you need more information. I'm not sure what information is helpful and not.

Comment: Can you post the manifest and styles?